# set class on non selected dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several select dropdowns each with a class `"glass-multi-select"`

I want to add class `'input-validation-error'` but only on those selects that dont have anything selected i.e this one is displayed

```
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
```

How can I achieve this with jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".glass-multi-select").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === "" ) {
        $(this).addClass('input-validation-error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$(".glass-multi-select").each(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('input-validation-error', this.value == '');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PpLN6/).